# Values Cannot be read by MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in MySql, I have values in my database where there is a comma for example (Monday, Tuesday). It reads my data if there is only one inside like (Monday) or (Tuesday) but when the data is more than 1 and with a comma MySQL doesn't read it. I've tried CHARINDEX but it didn't work or maybe I used the wrong syntax. thanks for your help.

Here's a snippet where I want to read my data

```
IF (DATE_FORMAT(TS.`date`, '%w') <>  R.`number`, 0, 1) AS 'restday'
```

I tried

```
IF (CHARINDEX(DATE_FORMAT(TS.`date`, '%w') <>  R.`number`, 0, 1)) AS 'restday'
```

but it sends an error message

Comment: If you are storing things as a comma separated list, you have a design problem. Put it in a relational table.

Comment: [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) takes an existing date value and converts it to a formatted string. If your column stores weekdays like `Monday, Tuesday`, you would need `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it _into_ a date.  If `TS.date` actually holds a date value rather than the name of a weekday, please clarify your question with sample data.

Comment: Please show table schema(s) and some sample data